# Changing gain of audio signal while it's playing causes artifacts

Tags: c++, audio, real-time, signal-processing, juce

I am playing back audio files in a program, and in the audio rendering callbacks, I apply a gain multiplier to the input signal and add it to the output buffer. Here's some pseudo code to illustrate my actions:

```
void audioCallback(AudioOutputBuffer* ao, AudioInput* ai, int startSample, int numSamples){
    for (int i=startSample; i<numSamples+startSample; i++){
        ao[i] = ai[i]*gain;
    }
}
```

Basically I just multiply the data by some multiplier. In this case, `gain` is a float member that is being adjusted via a GUI callback. If I adjust this value while the audio is still playing, I can hear that the audio is getting softer or louder when I move the slider, but I hear lots of little pops and clicks.

Not really sure what the deal is. I know about interpolation, and I do that if the audio is pitch shifted, but I'm not sure if I need to do any extra interpolation or something if the gain is being adjusted in real time before the audio file is finished playing.

If I adjust the slider before the audio start playing, the gain is set properly and I get no clicks.

Am I missing something here? How else is gain implemented but a multiplier on the input signal?

Comment: This is because ao[i] is probably overflowing by max number for example if the maximum number is 255 and you are trying to store higher values, it will be clipped causing the artifacts.

Comment: I tried it with a gain multiplier range from 0.0 to 1.0, in which case the multiplier would never increase the signal, so it's definitely not a clipping issue. I also verified this by printing out all of the raw audio output values (which I know causes artifacts to print in realtime, but it clips without any printing).

Comment: try it without gain. Does it clip? if so, you probably have sth wrong in the original signal, otherwise I don't other reason that overflowing.

Comment: also make sure both buffers are the same type, for example; unsigned 16.

Comment: there are no artifacts if I don't change the gain in real time. If i apply the gain but don't change it while the audio is playing back, there are no artifacts. It is only when changing the gain multiplier while the audio is still playing that there are artifacts. If i remove the gain altogether there is no clipping.

Comment: both buffers are the same type

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Question: how does the multiplication operator know which operand is the audio signal and which one is the gain? Answer: it doesn't. *They're both audio signals*, and anything audible in either one will be audible in the output.

A flat, unchanging signal doesn't produce any audible sounds. As long as the gain remains constant, it won't introduce any sound of its own.

A signal that changes abruptly will be *very* audible, it sounds like a click, containing lots of high frequencies.

As you've determined on your own, one way to reduce the high frequency content and thus the audibility is to stretch out the change over a number of samples, using a constant slope. This would certainly suffice in an application where you have lots of time to make the gain change.

Another way would be to run a low-pass filter on the gain signal and use *that* as the input to the multiplication.

Comment: That explains why when I change mix on something I'm working on, I get clicking... facepalm moment!

Answer (score 2):

I fixed it by changing the gain in increments of the amount changed. For instance, if the gain multiplier was set to 1.0, then changed to 0.8, that's a difference of 0.2 gain. For each sample in the callback, add the difference / numSamples to the previous volume to create a slurring or gradual gain change.

Comment: This is correct. An abrupt change in the gain results in lots of high frequencies in the gain signal. This is reflected in the result, as it is effectively a combination of both signals. "Slurring" the change drastically reduces the high frequency content.